# press the button continuously doesn't work after running macro with cnee

Tags: keyboard, macro

When I play a recorded macro with `cnee`, pressing a key continuously doesn't work anymore until the next system start. Is this a known problem?

Comment: Extra information: https://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?295187-does-anyone-have-experience-with-xnee-cnee-as-a-macro-recorder, https://xnee.wordpress.com/ (which is where http://www.gnu.org/software/xnee appears to redirect to)

Comment: Do you mean keys no longer autorepeat? There's an option `--keep-autorepeat` but I don't know what it does. Dump the autorepeat table with `xset q` before running cnee and again after to see if it differs.